# rewrite REMOTE_USER in nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, header, http-headers

I have an nginx instance behind apache. I have a rewrite in apache to pass the REMOTE_USER through to the backend:

```
<Proxy *>
    ...
    RewriteRule .* - [E=PROXY_USER:%{LA-U:REMOTE_USER}]
    RequestHeader add Proxy-User %{PROXY_USER}e
    RequestHeader add Remote-User %{PROXY_USER}e
</Proxy>
```

So in my backend nginx instance, i can see the env variables HTTP_PROXY_USER and HTTP_REMOTE_USER.  Good.

Rather than fork off my authentication code to pick up HTTP_REMOTE_USER rather than REMOTE_USER, is there a way i can force nginx to rewrite the header for me?